# How near to the maximum pointer value can an object be to avoid overflow?

Tags: c++, pointers

How close to the maximum value can a valid pointer be (as a global, allocated on the stack, `malloc`, `new`, `VirtualAlloc`, or any other alloc method a program/library might use), such that `ptr + n` risks overflowing?

I come across a lot of code that adds values to pointers when dealing with strings/arrays (in C++ sometimes also in a generic "random access iterator" template function).

e.g.

```
auto end = arr_ptr + len; //or just whatever some_container.end() returns
for (auto i = begin; i < end; ++i) { ... }
for (auto i = begin; i + 2 <= end; i += 2) { ...i[0]...i[1]... }
if (arr_ptr + 4 <= end && memcmp(arr_ptr, "test", 4) == 0) { ... }
if (arr_ptr + count > end) resize(...);
```

Would it be valid for the last array element to end on 0xFFFFFFFF (assuming 32bit), such that `end == 0`? If not, how close can it be?

I think always using `p != end` (and only ever adding 1) or taking the length as `len = end - begin` then using that (e.g. `(end - begin) >= 4`) is always safe, but wondering if it is actually an issue to look out for, and audit and change existing code for.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the language standard does not define this (neither C nor C++), and that it depends on the underlying HW architecture (memory management unit, virtual memory size, paging, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard doesn't talk about pointer overflow, it talks about what pointer values can legitimately be formed by pointer arithmetic. Simply put, the legitimate range is pointers into your object/array plus a one-past-the-end pointer.

Then, it is the responsibility of the C or C++ implementation not to create any objects in locations where some implementation-specific danger like pointer overflow prevents those legitimate pointer values from working correctly.

So neither `malloc` etc, nor the stack (presuming you haven't exceeded any stack bounds) will give you an array of `char`, starting at an address to which you cannot (due to overflow) add the size of the array.

> how close can it be?

As close as allows all the required pointer values to work correctly. So on this 32-bit system, a 1-byte object starting at `0xFFFFFFFE` would be the maximum possible address. The standard doesn't permit you to add `2` to the address, so it "doesn't matter" that doing so would overflow, so far as the implementation is concerned. For a 2-byte object the max would be `0xFFFFFFFD` if the type is unaligned, but that's an odd number, so `0xFFFFFFFC` if it requires 2-alignment.

Of course, other implementation details might dictate a lower limit. For example, it's not unusual for a system to reserve a page of memory either side of 0 and make it inaccessible. This helps catch errors where someone has accessed a null pointer with a small offset. Granted, this is more likely to happen with positive offsets than negative, but still. If your 32-bit system decided to do that, then `malloc` would need to take account of it, and would never return `0xFFFFFFFE`.

Comment: So practically speaking, any "malloc(n)" function requires "malloc(n) <= UINTPTR_MAX - n", but that is the only guarantee, and adding greater than 1 (sizeof(T) bytes) to any valid pointer is a potential bug to be fixed? And so "end - begin >= 4" is correct, but "begin + 4 <= end" is unsafe.

Comment: More or less. But there's rarely any benefit to thinking in terms of the numeric values of addresses. It's not actually guaranteed that `uintptr_t` exists, or that overflow is the only restriction on what pointers can be formed. Adding more than the size of the array has undefined behaviour, and hence is a potential bug, regardless of whether the underlying reason is arithmetic overflow or some different implementation detail that the programmer has never even heard of.

Comment: I only used UINTPTR_MAX because "VOID_PTR_MAX" does not. "((T*)malloc(sizeof(T))) + 1 for any 'allocation method' is always defined and cant overflow" might be a better terming?

Comment: @FireLancer: yes, you've got it :-) I'm too lazy to look up the exact reference, but IIRC this is all defined under addition in the "operators" sections of the C and C++ standards.